# Changing image on button using JS

Tags: javascript, html

This sounds simple but am having some difficulty.

I have a button that does various bit of code, like this:

`document.getElementById('frm_accountId').disabled = false;`

This is fine, however, naturally the button, that does it, want to display a lock icon and when clicked the icon wants to be changed to an unlocked icon.

```
<button id="button_unlock" type="button" onClick="unlock(this)"><img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/icons/stock_lock.png"/></button>
```

so the bit i want to change is the

`<img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/icons/stock_lock.png"/>`.

Is it possible to assign that to a `php` variable and change this using JS, I think not but thats what I want to do.

Thanks

Comment: Try like this <img src="'" + <?=base_url();?> + "assets/images/icons/stock_lock.png'" />

Comment: Why not use a sprite image and simply use JS to adjust the position?

Comment: I dont understand, the image source works fine, i want js to change it on click to a different image. I need help with the JS?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the innerHTML and change that

```
document.getElementById("button_unlock").innerHTML ="<img src='unlock.jpg'/>" ;
```

But better would be to add a css class to your button and define a background-image. Then when clicking it change the class to a class with another image.

```
.lock {
    background-image: url(lock.jpg);
    }

.unlock {
    background-image: url(unlock.jpg);
    }


<button id="button_unlock" type="button" onClick="unlock(this);" class="lock"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how the image can be toggled. It uses a `data-locked` attribute to maintain its state, and uses an object literal to define the image paths. The advantage of this method is it will work with multiple buttons and images, each one will maintain a separate state because the code works relatively with the child `<img>` of the targetted button.

```
var images = {
    locked : '<?=base_url();?>assets/images/icons/stock_lock.png',
    unlocked : '<?=base_url();?>assets/images/icons/stock_unlock.png'
};

function toggleLocked(buttonElement)
{
    var locked = buttonElement.getAttribute("data-locked") == "1";

    locked = !locked;
    buttonElement.setAttribute("data-locked", locked ? "1" : "0");

    buttonElement.children[0].src = locked ? images.locked : images.unlocked;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button_unlock" type="button" data-locked="1" onClick="toggleLocked(this)"><img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/images/icons/stock_lock.png"/></button>
```